# Script Shape color change in After Effects

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I am trying to write a script that creates a rectangle, and then changes its color from the default "Red", in After Effects.

Here's what I have. It creates the shape, but never changes the "Fill 1" color.

```
function createBackgroundShape() {

    var currentComp = app.project.activeItem;

    if (currentComp) {
        var shapeLayer = currentComp.layers.addShape();
        var shapeGroup =  shapeLayer.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Group");

        shapeGroup.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Shape - Rect");
        shapeGroup.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke");
        shapeGroup.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Graphic - Fill");

        var myRGBColor = [0, 255, 0, 255]/255;

        shapeLayer.content("Group 1").content("Fill 1").color = myRGBColor;        

        shapeLayer.content("Group 1").content("Stroke 1").color = myRGBColor;

    }
}

createBackgroundShape ()
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It should be:

```
shapeLayer.content("Group 1").content("Fill 1").color.setValue(myRGBColor);
```